# Simple meteor template helper not rendering in blaze

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I can't access my data from my template helper into my template. It's so strange because I have done it 100x. Here is a simple example. I am able to do it on other route/template combinations I have setup but for some reason not on this one.

My console is empty and that console.log('helper ran') never runs as far as I can tell

In my departmentBH1.html

```
<template name="departmentBH1">
  <h1>WTF</h1>
  <h1>{{hospital}}</h1>
</template>
```

In my departmentBH1.js

```
Template.departmentBH1.helpers = ({
  hospital: function() {
    console.log('helper ran');
    return 'test';
  }
});
```

In my router.js

```
Router.route('/bh/departmentBH1', {
  name: 'departmentBH1'
});
```

which renders without the proper text from the helper

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
Template.departmentBH1.helpers({
  hospital: function() {
    console.log('helper ran');
    return 'test';
  }
});
```

**Changed from `helpers = ({` to `helpers({`**

Comment: geeze, much much much appreciated, i'll accept that answer in 7 minutes when it lets me

Comment: No problem, please select best answer if you don't mind.